# Is there a way to know which browser addon is this?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons

Just by looking at the icon, is it possible to know what browser addon is it?

[image]

For context, during a screen presentation by a user, I noticed that these two addons were being used which I found to be intriguing (as to what they do). I forgot to get in touch with the presenter to inquire about it. So was wondering if this can be known (maybe perhaps via reverse image search?)

Comment: The second one (green) is Grammarly.

Answer (score 2):

The second is Grammarly.
First one looks like something from CrowdStrike but it's not.

Maybe it's possible to enlarge the picture then use simple image search via Google

Comment: Yeh, unfortunately, I took the screenshot during the presentation. It's as big as it can be. But Grammarly is spot on

Comment: Ok, I enlarged the image and it seems like here is the original: pngkit.com/png/detail/121-1210754_vector-freeuse-library-bird-culture-textile-mood-board.png Problem is: seems like it is not used for any specific chrome extension - found as previously used in some twitter extensions and on some GitHub projects

Comment: Looks very much like it. That's some nice detective work though.